# How is this "current sense resistor" selected?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, current-source, mosfet-driver, power-factor-correction

I attempt to design a PFC by [L6562A](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6562a.pdf). In the [corresponding application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/72/e5/be/2c/74/20/45/bb/CD00195944.pdf/files/CD00195944.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00195944.pdf) is mentioned that the amount of current sense resistor should be calculated from the following relation.

[image]

My problem is the "<" sign. does it mean the lower values are also suitable? According to my understanding, the max value of inverting input of PWM comparator is exactly 1 V due to the highlighted Zener that is corresponding to maximum current. So the exact calculated value of the resistor must be applied not lower.

[image]

On the other hand, why there is also a "Vcs,max" available that causes higher amounts of current to pass through Rs? It's nonsense to me.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boost inductor's maximum peak current occurs at the minimum input voltage and the maximum load.

The voltage across the sense resistor is used "to measure" the inductor current. And inductor current is kinda reflection of the load current. So, by sampling the CS pin's voltage, the chip can shape the PWM signal and detect any overload (look at the comparator in the block diagram. Its output goes to the RESET input of the SRFF).

If you select a higher resistor for RCS, it'll develop higher voltage for the same amount of current. And this may stop the PWM oscillator by mistake even if there's no overload because the voltage at CS pin will reach 1V quite earlier.

So you need to select the RCS **low enough** to detect **at least** maximum load condition even if the input voltage is maximum. This is where the < sign comes from.

As for the zener voltage, you can never guarantee a 1V zener to have exactly 1.0V zener voltage. There's always a deviation coming from the production and chemical processes. The values seen on the datasheet are statistical values. Since your first aim is to detect an overload, you need to use the minimum ref voltage. That's why its minimum value is used in the calculations.

Comment: In general, there is a trade-off when it comes to current sensing resistors. With higher values, you obviously get a bigger voltage to read. OTOH, you really need as small a resistance as possible to not interfere with the circuit.

Comment: @Dirk Bruere & Rohat Kılıç ; but are we allowed to use a lower resistor (for example 0.3 or 0.2 ohms)? in my opinion, the answer is no. because higher amounts of current would be allowed to flow then.

Comment: @Kamran you can't just put a random resistance lower than calculated. Its suggested value is lower than 1.0V/2.89A=0.346 Ohms. This does not mean that you can safely put, say, 0.1 Ohms. Of course, the allowed peak current will be higher if you do so. This may lead to the inductor's core saturation and thus some other problems as well. That's why the designer chose the nearest value (0.34 Ohms). As I stated in my answer, it should be low enough to allow and measure the max peak current. And, as Dirk stated in his comment, it should be high enough for the chip to sample the current easier.

Comment: And, fortunately for 0.34 Ohm selected value, it can be made of two parallel 0.68 Ohm resistors of E12 series of preferred numbers :) (*According to the result two parallel resistors of 0.68 Ω with 0.25 W of power rating have been selected* -- AN2761, p21/36)

Comment: @V.V.T absolutely.